# the views or views?

Tags: definite-article, plural-forms

> *I hope your video gets views it deserves*.
>
> *I hope your video gets **the** views it deserves*.

Is there any difference in meaning between these sentences? Are they both correct?

Comment: You should say 'the views'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are really trying to say here is:

> I hope your video gets the [great number of] views it deserves.

with the 'great number of' part implied rather than explicitly stated.

I think your first sentence (with the null article) sounds "off." Another way you could phrase this would be:

> I hope your video gets **many** views, as it deserves.

However, your second sentence actually sounds quite natural and idiomatic:

> ***I hope your video gets the views it deserves.***

That construct – *gets the ________ it deserves* – is actually rather common, and can be found many contexts, such as:

- Sports: ***Xavier basketball is finally getting the [respect](http://www.sbnation.com/college-basketball/2016/10/4/13154080/xavier-basketball-preview-trevon-bluiett-edmond-sumner) it deserves***
- Film: ***‘Planet Earth 2’ Gets The [Gorgeous Trailer](http://uproxx.com/tv/planet-earth-2-trailer/) It Deserves***
- The Arts: ***The botched Jesus fresco gets the [opera](http://www.theverge.com/2016/8/12/12454212/potato-jesus-ecce-homo-opera-musical-spain) it deserves***
- Politics: ***Every nation gets the [government](http://www.al.com/opinion/index.ssf/2016/09/we_get_the_government_we_deser.html) it deserves***
- Technology: ***Great software that finally gets the [hardware](http://www.todayonline.com/tech/gadgets/great-software-finally-gets-hardware-it-deserves) it deserves***

Comment: @43259 - You might want to wait more than 3 minutes; see our [not so fast](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) post on meta.